# filtering one textfile with an other textfile using single words

Tags: php

Here is what I have got right now. it filters a piece of text from a `.txt` file. my problem is that `$filter` has to be at the start of the line. I need the filter to be able to be anywhere in the line.

```
<?php

$input = file("PATH/TO/file1", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$filter = file("PATH/TO/file2", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$result = array_filter($input, function($line)use($filter){
    if(in_array(substr($line, 0, strpos($line, " ")), $filter))
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
});

file_put_contents("PATH/TO/file3", implode(PHP_EOL, $result));

?>
```

Here is an example file for `PATH/TO/file2`:

```
info1
info2
```

Here is an example file for `PATH/TO/file1`:

```
1232131-72-427-Q john info1 johnson -----more data----------more data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
8765438-43-542-T peter dudeson -----more info3 data----- -----more  data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
3456 info 6 761-21-742-G frank zena -----more data----------more data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
0924560-23-124-O marin franklin -----more info4 data----------more data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
2345333-21-423-P pin dudeson-----more data----------more info2 data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
5434225-21-983-A chow info5 ching -----more data----------more data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data<br>
```

Here is an example file for `PATH/TO/file3`:

```
1232131-72-427-Q john info1 johnson -----more data----------more data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
2345333-21-423-P pin dudeson-----more data----------more info2 data-----
More dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore dataMore data
```

The results have to be two lines each but the keyword wont ever be in the second line. is this even possible?

Comment: what should the final result look like?

Comment: file3 has to be the result  =)

Comment: you want a new line after the first column?

Comment: the result has to go to a txt file and has to be two lines each, it has to find the info tag and take two lines than find the next tag in the third line. then take another extra line then it has to take the fifth line and find the info tag and so on. the info tags are in file two and are acting as a filter. if a line doesnt have the word info in it it has to skip the line. when a line does have the word info in it it has to take the line and the line after it and write it to a txt file(full lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$input = file("./file1", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$filter = file("./file2", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$new_line = "\n";  // \r\n
$result = "";

function pass_filter($line, $filter) {
    $i = count($filter);
    $res = false;
    while (--$i > -1 ) {
        if (strrpos($line, $filter[$i]) > 0) {
            $res = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}



for ($j = 0; $j < count($input); $j++) {

    if ( pass_filter($input[$j], $filter) ) {
        $result .= $input[$j] . $new_line . $input[($j+1)] . $new_line;
    }
    $j++;
}

file_put_contents("./file3",$result);

?>
```